# How does Google Chrome's "Warn you if passwords are exposed in a data breach" feature work?

Tags: passwords, privacy, password-management, chrome

This feature is enabled by default. It says the usernames and passwords would be encrypted before sending to google. But google would know the encryption keys it used and to compare it with leaked username/password combinations the google servers has to decrypt it at some point. I use different passwords for different websites. Does that mean Google have been transporting all those to Google servers while this feature was enabled. Isn't it a huge privacy violation?

Comment: For the technical details see https://security.googleblog.com/2019/02/protect-your-accounts-from-data.html. To cite from there *"We designed Password Checkup with privacy-preserving technologies to never reveal this personal information to Google. We also designed Password Checkup to prevent an attacker from abusing Password Checkup to reveal unsafe usernames and passwords."*

Comment: Maybe, just maybe it sends a partial hash just like HaveIBeenPwned does it via the API? Pure speculation at this point. But I have to say it's a good question

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Your quote is just google saying 'don't worry, trust us, it's fine'. Maybe your link gives an explanation on how they actually do it, then that should be an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @quarague: As I explicitly said in my comment - the link gives the technical details.  It makes no sense though to replicate everything from the link in an answer if the OP could simply use the link to study it. A link-only answer is not a good idea either, hence only the comment. The citation from the link is only to address the specific privacy concerns of the OP, for the details they should consult the link itself.